# Using matplotlib 3D scatter, 3rd dimension is being ignored

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I have a dataset, which works fine for two dimensions, but all values for third dimension are set at zero, even though values are there:

```
>>> x
[[-1.731428 -8.946514  0.274677]
 [-1.056165  2.154681  9.164814]
 [ 2.746465 -3.161551 -7.168484]
 ...
 [and so on.....]
```

I.e. dataset clearly has three columns of non-zero values. To make the scatter plot I use following code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3D import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
plt.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], x[:,2], marker='o')
plt.show()
```

And what I get is the following:

[image]

Other two dimensions work fine.
Also if I define dataset by hand, it works fine as well:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, -7, 2]
c = [1, 5, 0, 1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
plt.scatter(a, b, c, marker='o')
plt.show()
# WORKS FINE
```

Is the problem in the way how is my data stored? I tried to look up, but I could not find it.

Comment: have you tried printing out `x[:,0], x[:,1], x[:,2]` individually before calling `scatter()`? if yes, are the outputs of `x[:,2]` non-zero?

Comment: yes, I have tried, and they are non-zero

Comment: try storing them individually in a variable, and assigning them?

Comment: did not solve anything

Comment: `plt.scatter` might not know to use `ax`. Do `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')` and then `ax.scatter(...)`. If this is not the issue, [edit] your question with a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce your problem.